# property expressions not working in quarkus native

Tags: java, quarkus

I have the following property in my application.properties

```
// application.properties
LOCAL.JWT_PUBLIC_KEY=${JWT_PUBLIC_KEY:KEY_JWT}
```

And I'm injecting that property using the microprofile config anotation ConfigProperty

```
// OnPremiseSecrets.java
public JwtConfig(@ConfigProperty(name = "LOCAL.JWT_PUBLIC_KEY") String jwtPublicKey)
```

it works perfectly while running the program in JVM with a compiled jar quarkusDev
but it doesn't work in a native graalvm compilation, in the logs it return KEY_JWT as jwtPublicKey value which is the default.

I tried reading enviernment variables directry using

```
System.getenv
```

and it returns the right value, the environment variable is configured

Comment: I've tried reproducing the problem with your description, but everything seems to work as expected. Any change you can provide me with your reproducer that shows the issue? Thanks!

Comment: thanks for reading the question, I'm assigning thath variables in a bean, I see that the class is initialized at compile time so it keeps the same environment variable's value that had when it was compiled
I tried --initialize-at-run-time but it did'n work since its a bean

Comment: Ah, so this really depends on how you are using the bean. In certain situations, Quarkus will eagerly initialize the bean and take the configuration used during the build, so you won't see a difference when you change it in runtime. An example is JAX-RS Providers, which are initialized during the native image build. For these cases, you should use `Instance<T>` injection, so you get an updated value.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand, can you detail this Instance<T> solution?

Comment: Try `@ConfigProperty(name = "LOCAL.JWT_PUBLIC_KEY") Instance<String> jwtPublicKey`.